# R: Merging rows by duplicates in first column

Tags: r, merge, duplicates

I have a large dataset with duplicated values in the first column, like so:

```
ID         date      var1   var2
person1    052016    509    1678  
person2    122016    301    NA
person1    072016    NA     45
```

I want to combine the IDs and to take the most recent value by "date", and if it`s NA - to take the last value that it's not NA. 
The output should be like this:

```
ID         date      var1   var2 
person2    122016    301    NA
person1    072016    509    45
```

I have tried with this, but it didn't worked.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise_all(funs(max(data$date))) %>% funs(first(.[!is.na(.)]))
```

What should I use to apply a working code to the whole dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr).

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  arrange(ID, desc(date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(first(.[!is.na(.)]))) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   ID        date  var1  var2
#   <chr>    <int> <int> <int>
# 1 person1  72016   509    45
# 2 person2 122016   301    NA
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID         date      var1   var2
person1    '052016'    509    1678  
person2    '122016'    301    NA
person1    '072016'    NA     45",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse` and `fill` function.
Load data:

```
Mar_df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("person1", 
"person2"), class = "factor"), date = c(52016L, 122016L, 72016L
), var1 = c(509L, 301L, NA), var2 = c(1678L, NA, 45L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"date", "var1", "var2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Then:

```
Mar_df_summarised <- Mar_df %>% 
    arrange(ID,date) %>%
    fill(...=var1,.direction="down") %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise_all(.funs=funs(last(.)))
```

The result is:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  ID        date  var1  var2
  <fctr>   <int> <int> <int>
1 person1  72016   509    45
2 person2 122016   301    NA
```